# Can I use iPhoneBrowser to upload a directory structure to Office Connect?

Tags: ipod-touch, ms-office

I want to use my iPod touch to view and edit word documents.  I've found a free app (Office Connect) that seems to allow this.  However, the way that this app wants you to upload files is to connect to an IP address and upload files one at a time.  I have a while directory structure for my files that I want to maintain, and I have too many files to upload them one at a time.

I've come across another app called iPhoneBrowser, which appears to fill this gap.  However, I can't fathom the directory structure of my iPod.  For example, the OfficeConnect app comes with a sample document called "QuickOffice.doc", but I can't find this in iPhoneBrowser.

Am I missing something here - can I use iPhoneBrowser for this, or if not, is there another app that does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paid version of quick office (quick office connect mobile suite I think it's called) allows you to add various online storage services: google docs, dropbox, box.net and mobile me. You upload/sync your files on your computer to one of these services then add your account to quick office and you will be able to access and write to the files on the service you added.

Quickoffice also has local storage where you can download files to from one of the services. This is useful if you know you'll want to access a big file when your not on wifi. You can download it while on wifi and then access it later offline.

And vice versa you can create a document locally when and the upload it to a service later.

Each iPhone app has it's own sandbox which it can modify and read. It can't see or modify any other apps sandbox. So iPhone browser will only see files you added using iPhone browser. iOS 4 now has a documents facilty where if an app can read a word document such as quickoffice it registers that it cam do that and if an app can list files such as the official dropbox app you can open a document in the dropbox app and it will show a Hutton which you can press to open the document in quick office.

Quickoffice also has the ability to openema attachments. However I haven't used this so I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to get [DataViz's Documents To Go](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/iphone/). It provides the capability of editing Word documents on your iOS device and the 'premium' version interfaces with Dropbox (or similar services) to synchronize the changes to and from your PC. I haven't personally used their iOS version, but I did use their Palm version several years ago and it worked quite well.

> **Microsoft Word Editing**
>
> View, edit and create Microsoft Word documents on the go and experience the freedom of being able to review and update any of the Word documents you rely upon; anytime, anywhere. Advanced viewing and editing features include touch navigation, cut/copy/paste, bulleted and numbered lists, fonts, embedded pictures, tables, word count, password-protected files and the ability to edit in landscape view.
>
> **Online/Cloud Documents Support**
>
> **('Documents To Go Premium' only)**
>   Download, view and edit your files from your Google Docs, Box.net, Dropbox, MobileMe iDisk or SugarSync account directly in Docs To Go. Any changes you make can be saved and synchronized back to the online account so that you'll always have the most up-to-date version. You can even create new files in Docs To Go and upload them immediately to your account.